# Extracting text from td tag containing br tags inside

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I want to extract text from td tag containing br tags inside.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = "<td class=\"text\">This is <br/>a breakline<br/><br/></td>"
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
print(soup.td.string)
```

Actual Output: `None`

Expected output: `This is a breakline`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will give you what you are looking for:

```
print(soup.td.text)
```

This is for the specific `td` tag

Otherwise you also have:

```
print(soup.text)
```

Comment: What version of bs4 are you using?

Comment: I am using 4.6.0

Answer (score 2):

From Beautiful Soup [document](https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#string):

> If a tag contains more than one thing, then it’s not clear what `.string` should refer to, so `.string` is defined to be None:

And if you want text part *([document](https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#get-text))*:

> If you only want the text part of a document or tag, you can use the `get_text()` method. It returns all the text in a document or beneath a tag, as a single Unicode string:

So you can use following:

```
print(soup.get_text())
```

For specific tag `soup.td.get_text()`